# INET6 does not work with [::1]

Tags: linux, perl, ipv6

perl INET6 does not work with [::1]:port , where port is the 4 digit port number.
it works with 5 digit port number.
Any suggestions/work arounds?

Comment: Any 4 digit port number or just those below 1024?

Comment: Please improve your question to be more specific.

Answer (score 3):

On some systems, one must have special (root) privileges to bind to a port less than 1024.